While I try to Add my About Us page link in NAVBAR and then add that in the app.jsx the home page gets mixed with it and somehow it is a bit messy
When I attempt to add my "About Us" page link to the Navbar and include it in app.jsx, the home page ends up getting mixed up and becomes a bit messy. Specifically, when I don't add the Navbar links, everything works perfectly fine. However, when I try to include, for example, the "About Us" link within the Home section of the Navbar, I encounter an issue where the styles for the About page overlap with those of the Home page.
NAVBAR Image please Refer this Image for your reference
Home Page Image  Look at this Image This is the site which I want when I add the aboutUs page in the navbar
but when I add or route the about us page in the App.jsx my homepage get's distorted like this
Distorted Home Page  Image This is how the iamge looks like When I add the AboutUs in the Route
Here is the code for both
Navbar.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css'; // Import the CSS file
import gsap from 'gsap'; // Make sure gsap is installed and imported
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(location.pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
      let tl = gsap.timeline();
      
      tl.to("#nav-bottom", {
        height: "21vh",
        duration: 0.5
      })
      .to(".nav-part2 h5", {
        display: "block",
        duration: 0.1
      })
      .to(".nav-part2 h5 span", {
        y: 0,
        stagger: {
          amount: 0.5
        }
      });
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      let tl = gsap.timeline();
      
      tl.to(".nav-part2 h5 span", {
        y: 25,
        stagger: {
          amount: 0.2
        }
      })
      .to(".nav-part2 h5", {
        display: "none",
        duration: 0.1
      })
      .to("#nav-bottom", {
        height: 0,
        duration: 0.2
      });
    };

    nav.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
    nav.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);

    return () => {
      nav.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
      nav.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenu(location.pathname);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <nav>
      <h1><span className="color3">CRAVE</span>Cart.</h1>
      <div className="nav-part2">
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4>Our Story</h4>
          <h5><span>Our Story</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4><Link to="/" className={menu === '/' ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setMenu('/')}>Home</Link></h4>
          <h5><span><Link to="/about" className={menu === '/about' ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setMenu('/about')}>About Us</Link></span></h5>
          <h5><span>How It Works</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Blog</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4>Mess</h4>
          <h5><span>Daily Specials</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Weekly Menu</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Meal Plans</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Student Discounts</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4>Track Order</h4>
          <h5><span>Order Status</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Delivery Timeline</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Recent Orders</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Track with Map</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4>Contact Us</h4>
          <h5><span>Customer Service</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Feedback</span></h5>
          <h5><span>FAQs</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-elem">
          <h4>About Agency</h4>
          <h5><span>Our Team</span></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <button>
        Login
        <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path fill="#fff" d="M2.5 14.375V17.5h3.125l9.217-9.217-3.125-3.125L2.5 14.375Zm14.758-8.508a.83.83 0 0 0 0-1.175l-1.95-1.95a.83.83 0 0 0-1.175 0l-1.525 1.525 3.125 3.125 1.525-1.525Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <div id="nav-bottom"></div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} /> {/* Optional: Route for the home page */}
        
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

when I add the Route option for my About Us page It gets overlapped on the Home page
AboutUs.jsx Code
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll'; // Import Locomotive Scroll
import gsap from 'gsap'; // Import GSAP
import './AboutUs.css'; // Make sure your CSS file path is correct

const AboutUs = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize Locomotive Scroll
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: document.querySelector('#main'),
      smooth: true,
    });

    // GSAP Animation Timeline
    const tl = gsap.timeline();

    tl.to('#page1', {
      y: '100vh',
      scale: 0.6,
      duration: 0,
    })
      .to('#page1', {
        y: '30vh',
        duration: 1,
        delay: 1,
      })
      .to('#page1', {
        y: '0vh',
        rotate: 360,
        scale: 1,
        duration: 0.7,
      });

    // Clean up Locomotive Scroll on component unmount
    return () => {
      scroll.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Scrolling text animation for page5
    const container = document.getElementById('page5');
    const scrollingText = container.querySelector('.scrolling-text');
    const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    const textWidth = scrollingText.scrollWidth;

    const animate = () => {
      let startPos = containerWidth;

      const step = () => {
        startPos -= 1; // Adjust the value to control the speed
        if (startPos <= -textWidth) {
          startPos = containerWidth;
        }
        scrollingText.style.transform = `translateX(${startPos}px)`;
        requestAnimationFrame(step);
      };
      step();
    };

    animate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div id="page1">
        <div id="nav">
          <h5>CarveCart</h5>
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <i className="ri-menu-3-line"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="elems">
          <div id="elem1">
            <div id="image-div">
              <img
                src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/52/38/80/360_F_252388016_KjPnB9vglSCuUJAumCDNbmMzGdzPAucK.jpg"
                alt="CarveCart"
              />
            </div>
            <h4>
              CARVECART <span>NEW</span>
            </h4>
            <p>
              CarveCart is an innovative food delivery platform, built on the
              powerful MERN stack. Our app streamlines the process of ordering
              from a wide selection of restaurants, with a focus on providing a
              seamless user experience for food lovers everywhere.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="elem2">
            <h2>OUR TEAM</h2>
            <h3>
              Arya Joshi & Ananya Chitale
              <br />
              talented developers —
              <br />
              behind CarveCart.
            </h3>
            <h6>Tip! Drag sideways to navigate</h6>
          </div>
          <div id="elem3">
            <div id="image-div">
              <img
                src="https://www.asokart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/6-Nataraja-600x805.jpg"
                alt="Visionaries"
              />
            </div>
            <h4>
              The visionaries behind CarveCart <span>NEW</span>
            </h4>
            <p>
              Arya and Ananya are the sole visionaries behind CarveCart, having
              designed and developed every core feature using cutting-edge
              technologies like React, MongoDB, Express, and Node.js. Their
              combined expertise has shaped the app into a seamless and
              intuitive platform for food delivery.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1>CraveCart.</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="page4">
        <div id="page4-left">
          <img
            src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f2429f172d117fcee10e819/605c679f33f67d3dd00b04b4_avatar-3.jpeg"
            alt="Founders"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="page4-right">
          <p>
            CRAVECart is here to make your food delivery experience effortless
            and enjoyable. Offering a wide range of dishes from local favorites
            to gourmet meals, we prioritize quality and convenience in every
            order.
            <br />
            Founded by Ananya Chitale and Arya Joshi, CRAVECart is dedicated to
            bringing you exceptional service with just a few clicks. Enjoy
            delicious meals delivered straight to your door!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page5">
        <div className="scrolling-text">
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
          {/* Duplicate content to ensure continuous scrolling */}
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Let's create something together <span>Email me</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutUs;


Home.jsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Header.css'; // Ensure this contains the necessary CSS
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

const Header = () => {
  // Register ScrollTrigger
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const loadingAnimation = () => {
      const tl = gsap.timeline();

      tl.from("#page1", {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.2,
        delay: 0.2,
      })
      .from("#page1", {
        transform: "scaleX(0.7) scaleY(0.2) translateY(80%)",
        borderRadius: "150px",
        duration: 2,
        ease: "expo.out",
      })
      .from("nav", {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5,
        delay: -1,
      })
      .to("nav", {
        opacity: 1, // Ensure navbar becomes visible
        duration: 0.5
      })
      .from("#page1 h1, #page1 p, #page1 div", {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5,
        stagger: 0.2,
      });
    };

    // Call the animation function when the component mounts
    loadingAnimation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <nav className="visible">
        {/* Your nav content goes here */}
      </nav>
      
      <div id="page1">
        <h1>
          <span className="color">Fast</span> cravings,{" "}
        </h1>
        <h1>
          D
          <span>
            <svg className="c-bttn__morph" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 131 136">
              <path
                className="g-path"
                data-morph="end"
                fill="#fff"
                d="M48 77.457v7.224h7.224l21.307-21.306-7.224-7.225L48 77.457Zm34.118-19.67a1.919 1.919 0 0 0 0-2.716l-4.508-4.508a1.919 1.919 0 0 0-2.716 0l-3.526 3.526 7.224 7.224 3.526-3.525Z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </span>
          ne with <span className="color2">ease.</span>
        </h1>
        <p>
          Delivering deliciousness to your doorstep with speed and simplicity.{" "}
          <br /> seamless dining with our cutting-edge technology
          <br />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="page2"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;


Here is the codesandBox link Check the App.jsx to make the changes:
https://codesandbox.io/p/live/8355c488-0788-48ab-ab64-93934edc4cd8

Are you asking about some issue with a link in the nav bar, or something about some "about us" page that you are not showing us? Please [edit] to clarify what the specific issue is and include a complete and accurate [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

I have added the required images Please look into it and do help me

Seems like a CSS issue IMO. Images are helpful to illustrate an issue, but a [mcve] is still desired so we can see what the code is doing. React-Router hasn't much of anything to do with styling.

Ok I'll add both the codes Navbar as well as Home page code

FWIW you might also try creating a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live. Don't forget to include or explain any exact reproduction steps if they are necessary.

If you are still not getting the problem please do let me know I'll add the sandbox link

I think a sandbox would be helpful.

I have added the link please go and check it out moreover change the app.jsx route command to see the change

Did you save your files? That link opens what appears to be a base Vite project.

I didn't get it like can you show me how to make the changes in the Sandbox Itself I have given you the permissions to edit it

It's like almost any other IDE where you simply save your changes. I think they even automatically save by default these days in CodeSandbox. Then there's a share button in the upper-right corner which copies the short URL to the clipboard for easy sharing.

I have provided the link please do check

Sandbox code still appears to be some default Vite code/page. There's just the main App component with some count state and a button in the UI. Were you not able to edit it to include the code example from the post?

Sorry for the error from my side please have a look at the new link now Thank you

Issue
The issue here is "polluted" global CSS styling. When the <Route path='/about' element={<AboutUs />} /> route is added to the routes, the AboutUs component is imported, including its AboutUs.css file which is loaded into the DOM and applied. Many of your various CSS files all define rules targeting the same CSS selectors, so the AboutUs CSS styles are overriding various elements of your nav bar and header, and likely other routed components.
Compare for example the applied h1 element rules:
Without the AboutUs route and CSS

With the AboutUs route and CSS included

Note that AboutUs.css's #page1 h1 rule is applied even though the URL path is still "/" and the Home component is rendered.
AboutUs.css
#page1 h1 {
  font-size: 300px;
  letter-spacing: -25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: canopee;
  background-color: #1c1c19;
  color: #c4bcb3;
  line-height: 600px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

Solution
CSS is globally applied, so the solution is to limit the scope of your CSS rules via selectors. This is generally achieved by wrapping a specific page or section/area/etc in a class or some unique identifier.
Example:
AboutUs.jsx
Provide an "about-us" CSS classname to one of the component's root elements that wraps the page component's content.
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import gsap from "gsap";
import "./AboutUs.css";

const AboutUs = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div className="about-us" id="main-content"> // <-- "about-us" CSS classname
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default AboutUs;

AboutUs.css
Here I'm only showing a single rule, i.e. all h1 elements that are descendants of any elements with the "about-us" CSS classname, but this will be done for any CSS rules you want to apply and limit to the About page's content.
.about-us h1 {
  font-size: 300px;
  letter-spacing: -25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: canopee;
  background-color: #1c1c19;
  color: #c4bcb3;
  line-height: 600px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

You can see here that the AboutUs.css is loaded but the h1 element's CSS on the home page isn't polluted by the about page's CSS.


The answer is quite simple.
<div className="nav-elem">
          <h4><Link to="/" className={menu === '/' ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setMenu('/')}>Home</Link></h4>
          <h5><span><Link to="/about" className={menu === '/about' ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setMenu('/about')}>About Us</Link></span></h5>
          <h5><span>How It Works</span></h5>
          <h5><span>Blog</span></h5>
        </div>

Here, you are going to navigate to /about when clicking the About us but you didn't add the route to the App.jsx.
So the App.jsx should be like this.
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs/AboutUs'; // Import the About Us component
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} /> {/* Home page */}
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} /> {/* Optional: Duplicate home route */}
        <Route path='/about' element={<AboutUs />} /> {/* About Us page */}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


I tried that but after adding the Route command in the app.jsx it gets overlapped with the home distorting my hime page

*Home page typo error
